# Question title misaligned when title begins with "I"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title, navigation

[image: I is misaligned]

We can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632360/1068283) that the beginning of the question title, which starts with the English word "I", appears at the far right of the screen, below and to the right of the Ask Question link.

This should appear at the left, left-aligned below the Stack Overflow logo.

(This doesn't happen if the herobox is visible; close it to see the behavior.)

Seen on Chrome 28 in Linux, as well as Firefox 22. OS is Fedora 19 with KDE desktop; Chrome is as provided by Google's yum repo.

Comment: Not seeing it in Win7 FF22 / Chrome myself though. tried all sorts of different zoom setting too but it always displays as it should do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure _most_ people aren't seeing it. Doesn't seem to happen to me on Windows. But I only rarely use Windows...

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 27.0.1453.93 on Linux nor in Firefox 21 on Linux.

Comment: No problems on the latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari, on a Mac. (As an aside: the text in the buttons appears much bolder in my browsers.)

Comment: Which distribution/s (+versions) are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro (64 bit), Chrome 28.0.1500.72/IE 10.0.9200 - no problems.

Comment: @Oded This is occurring on Fedora 19 with KDE desktop. Using Google Chrome from Google's yum repo.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I don't have a Red Hat distro readily available, so this may have to wait a while for a repro, though it sounds like some shared library could be the source.

Comment: I see this too using OmniWeb 5.11.2 on Mac OS X 10.7: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GQy2P.png, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Oded It's just [a download away](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/)... :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I know... I know... Need to d/l, setup on a VM etc... No a weekend job ;)

Comment: Nice find, @Josh, assuming that all is fine in other browsers on the same Mac? Then we might rule out a font issue?

Comment: @Arjan: My Firefox is not up to date, I think -- version 21.0 -- but it and Safari 5.1.7 display the title without the weirdness.

Comment: Is it isolated to SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix will be in the next build.

Strangely, only happening for logged in users... Fedora 19, KDE, Chrome 28/Firefox 22.

Comment: Looks like the next build is already deployed.

Comment: @hims056 - Fedora 19, KDE, Chrome 28/Firefox 22 and logged in. Really specific set of conditions. Not deployed yet ;)

Comment: Ohh then no repro for me in Chrome 28/Firefox 22, Win XP. (Logged in)

Comment: @hims056 - I couldn't repro on Linux Mint either.